# Is read latency increased due to a big SSTable?

Tags: cassandra

If after a long period of time, STCS produced a really big SSTable, and later on we received a read request for a partition key that only exists in that big SSTable (i.e. it's unique across all the SSTables for that table), would the read latency be increased because we're dealing with a big SSTable, or is the read latency NOT influenced by the size of a partition index?

On a side note, I suppose that having the help of the partition summary and then using the partition index with pointers for just one big SSTable is still better than seeking a lot of smaller SSTables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is a single instance of **Partition Key Cache** by Cassandra process and it is shared by all SSTables and all tables. Its size limit is defined in `cassandra.yaml`

```
# Default value is empty to make it "auto" (min(5% of Heap (in MB), 100MB)). 
# Set to 0 to disable key cache.
key_cache_size_in_mb:
```

For the **Index Summary** that is used to perform binary search to find the nearest partition offset for scanning, normally we sample every 128 partition keys but for SSTables that have a lot of partition keys, this sampling can be increased to save memory.

```
CREATE TABLE music.example (
    id int PRIMARY KEY
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    ...
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    ...;
```

The total memory usage of **Index Summary** can be configured in `cassandra.yaml`

```
# A fixed memory pool size in MB for for SSTable index summaries. If left
# empty, this will default to 5% of the heap size. If the memory usage of
# all index summaries exceeds this limit, SSTables with low read rates will
# shrink their index summaries in order to meet this limit.  However, this
# is a best-effort process. In extreme conditions Cassandra may need to use
# more than this amount of memory.
index_summary_capacity_in_mb:

# How frequently index summaries should be resampled.  This is done
# periodically to redistribute memory from the fixed-size pool to sstables
# proportional their recent read rates.  Setting to -1 will disable this
# process, leaving existing index summaries at their current sampling level.
index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes: 60
```

See **[CASSANDRA-6379](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6379)**
So to reply your question, the read performance for big SSTable:

1. Can be fast if by chance you have a cache hit in **Partition Key Cache**
2. Will be slower because the index interval will be increased for big SSTable (**e.g. SSTable having a lot of distinct partition keys, it's not necessarily related to its size in absolute**)
3. Will be slower if your big SSTable is not frequently used, see **[CASSANDRA-5519](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5519)**

Comment: Thanks! Very clear answer! I had not taken the partition key cache into account, but this was assuming we got no hit on it. Still your answer made it pretty clear to me! :)